# How to combine posterior probabilities from different classifiers?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, graphical-model

I have four different images $(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4)$ which I classify with four different discriminate probabilistic models (discriminative classifiers) to obtain posterior probabilities of a pixel belonging to four classes i.e. in each case I obtain a vector four 4 indication membership values to the four classes. Assuming $C_1, C_2, C_3$ and $C_4$ to be class labels then the estimated posterior probabilities in each case as $P(C_1|X_1), P(C_2| X_2), P(C_2|X_3)$ and $P(C_4|X_4)$ . I wish to combine the probabilities from the 4 classifiers. So  assume $P(C_1)$, $P(C_2)$, $P(C_3)$ and $P(C_4)$ to represent the posterior probability values (and class conditional independence) I decided to determine their joint probability $P(C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4)$ which i solve using chain rule as: $$P(C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4) = P(C_1)\cdot P(C_1,C_2)/P(C_1)\cdot P(C_1,C_2, C_3)/P(C_1, C_2)\cdot P(C_1,C_2, C_3, C_4)/P(C_1, C_2, C_3)\textrm{.}$$ Is this justifiable  theoretically? I have gone through this article (http://www.mpia.de/Gaia/publications/probcomb_TN.pdf) but still did not get my case there clearly. Kindly advice.

Thanks

I posted a similar question in Research gate also as shown by the link below:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_combine_posterior_probabilities_from_different_classifiers#55bb43c06225ff26378b460f